# jQuery selector Exclude a Child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select the whole body but exclude a single element, how can I achieve this ?

```
$("body").not('#to-exclude').mouseup(function(){ 
  // ...
});
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery < 1.7 you should use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate);

```
$('body').delegate(':not(#to-exclude)', 'mouseup', function () {
    // ...
});
```

For jQuery 1.7 and up however, consider using the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method;

```
$('body').on('mouseup', ':not(#to-exclude)', function () {
    // ...
});
```

The reason your code isn't working is because the jQuery object you constructed with `$('body')` only includes the body element. Therefore `not()` can't remove the element, as it's not in there.

Answer (score 0):

it is another way.

```
$("body").mouseup(function(event){
if(event.target.id == "to-exclude"){
return false;
}else{

//do your works here
};

});
```